# How to grant full access to any new folders/files/subfolders created in a specific folder?

Tags: command-line, 20.04, permissions, acl

I have granted full access to a folder as follows:

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /media/sharedfolder
```

However when a new subfolder is created by User A, that subfolder is not accessible by other users. How can I automatically grant full access to any new folders/files/subfolder that are created in this folder?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Comment: never use 777. "others" have nothing to do on your external disk. Nor does "group" generally need execute permissions.  Better to use `750`. And you need to check your mount options. It probably is lacking mask , userid and or groupid settings,

Comment: I have no idea how to use masks - is this what is required to achieve what I want to do? This is the mount command: `UUID=bd4f641a-f011-49c6-ae4f-7ae9db49a3c1  /media/sharedfolder ext4    defaults,nofail   0    0`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Do not use Add Comment.

Comment: @Rinzwind, if you want users within the group, to be able to list the files in the directory, to be able to create subdirectories, or create new files within the directory, then they need execute permissions.  It is very common to have x permission for group.

As for never use 777, that is also incorrect, there are often times a tmp directory needs open permissions, you might have a upload directory on a webserver, allowing 777 on one directory, that is used for one specific reason is common. With that said, it is not recomended to use 777 often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **default** [ACLs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/setfacl.1.html)<sup>(*file access control lists*)</sup> **specific** to this particular directory like so:

```bash
for i in u g o
  do
    setfacl --default --modify "$i"::7 /media/sharedfolder
    done
```

... where `u g o` are `u`ser, `g`roup and `o`ther, the skipped empty field in `::` means any user/group, the `7` is a bit-wise combination of read (4),  write  (2),  and  execute
(1) which, in this case, is equivalent to `rwx` which can alternatively be used instead and  `/media/sharedfolder` is the desired target directory.

The target directory and any sub-directories/files to be created under it from now on will be set to those permissions by default.

However, on **files**, the execution bit is not set by default (not even with `umask 0000`) ... It'll need to be set manually after the files have been created if/when it's required ... Read and write bits, however, can be set by the default permissions.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I have run the script as suggested and it seems to have done the job perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

The mask of any file/directories created by a user is defined by the users umask.  The umask is generally set in the users .bashrc or via /etc/login.def system wide.

The standard umask in Ubuntu is 022 - this results in new files 644 and directories as 755.

*****NOTE Only use 777 if you are sure you want everyone to have permission to view, and run files within this directory, using 777 in the wrong place, is a major secuirty risk.**

If you really really want User A to create directories with a 777, then modify User A umask in .bashrc in the Users home directory.

Alternatively, you could create a little script eg:

file: /usr/bin/mkmediadir

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir $1
chmod 777 $1
```

set the script permissions to allow executable.

```
chmod +x /usr/bin/mkmediadir
```

now all User A needs to do when you want to create a new directory in /media/sharedfolder is run mkmediadir  and the permissions will be set.  This would remove the risk that User A creates a sensative directory with open permissions in error.

Comment: The default umask on Ubuntu is `0002` ... `0022` is under the `root`/`sudo` user ... Please compare `umask && sudo bash -c 'umask'` ... I hope I recalled correctly :)