# How to change permissions (chmod)?

Tags: command-line, permissions, 22.04, samba, chmod

I have created a folder not in `/home` but on other volume which is free (eventually I'd like to share the folder via Samba).

I have found the path:

```
/media/xduser/kingstone
```

I did:

```
cd /media/xduser/kingstone
sudo mkdir share23
sudo chmod 777 -R share23
sudo chown -R xduser:xduser  /media/xduser/kingstone/share23
```

But when I `ls`, I see:

```
$ ls -li /media/xduser/kingstone
total 32
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 xduser xduser 32768 Dec  7 09:48 share23
```

---

Also, I cannot change permissions in the GUI. So, I see the share23 on another machine but cannot open it because of permissions.

This is the output of `findmt`:

```
$ sudo findmnt -T /media/xduser/kingstone/
TARGET                 SOURCE    FSTYPE OPTIONS
/media/xduser/kingstone /dev/sdc1 vfat  rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,uid=1001,gid=1001,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=
```

How can I change the permissions?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `findmnt -T /media/xduser/kingstone`

Comment: That filesystem doesn't support Linux permissions ... But, you can change `fmask`, `dmask` to `0000` or probably remove them from your mount options and use `umask=0000` instead.

Comment: Also note that the permissions on the local machine are unlikely to be the problem on the remote machine. Those will depend on how the remote machine mounts the directory.

Comment: @Raffa thank you. I see, it is FAT. I can  format disk. What file system to use?

Comment: Any *nix filesystem should support Linux type permissions ... EXT4 is the default on Ubuntu ... However, Windows will not be able to read it directly, so you can't mount it on Windows ... You'll need to mount it on a Linux machine and then, Windows can read it as a Samba share for example

Comment: If you decide to use EXT4 for example, then you might want to modify ACLs instead. See for example https://askubuntu.com/a/1494895/968501 ... You might as well (with SAMBA) consider editing `smb.conf`. See for example https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206309

Comment: SSHFS is another option to be able to mount linux file systems in windows.

Comment: I have unmount, formatted (ext4) , mount the disk. Now It is visible in Disks, in FIles. But I cannot create a folder via GUI (greayed). I have created sudo mkdir shared17. But cannot chown: sudo chown -R xoleg:xoleg /media/xduser/112e86d7-fc5d-4d63-b04a-9f32e7160eb/media17
----chown: cannot access '/media/xduser/112e86d7-fc5d-4d63-b04a-9f32e7160eb/media17': No such file or directory

Comment: Did you mean to run `sudo chown -R xoleg:xoleg /media/xduser/112e86d7-fc5d-4d63-b04a-9f32e7160eb/shared17` instead of `sudo chown -R xoleg:xoleg /media/xduser/112e86d7-fc5d-4d63-b04a-9f32e7160eb/media17`  … Check the last directory name :)

Comment: Yes, thanx, I try to solve it using one, another user etc. But anyway:  I have created inside the media17 folder yet another folder media171, then I go to the directory and performed 2 commands sudo chown -R xoleg:xoleg media171
sudo chmod 777 -R media171 They completed without errors.

Comment: I have added a section to smb.config and now the folder is visible in remote machine but  I cannot open it because of permissions....

Comment: That folder might be affected by the permissions of its parent folders i.e. `media17` and up to the mount point itself i.e. `112e86d7-fc5d-4d63-b04a-9f32e7160eb` ... So, look into those as well.

Comment: Oh, yes, may be , the owner of media17 is root and permissions restricted. Why I cannot create a Folder in the /media/xoleg/112e86d7-fc5d-4d63-b04a-9f32e7160eb

Comment: The mount point `112e86d7-fc5d-4d63-b04a-9f32e7160eb` is also a folder so check its permissions and ownership … depending on how you mounted your drive, it could also be owned by `root` and with restricted permissions

Answer (score 2):

##### It's a free world, but ...

Assuming you understand that granting full permissions of read, write, and execute and especially for the `other` group is going to compromise the security and probably integrity/existence (*given the sticky bit isn’t set as well*) of all files under that directory allowing anyone to view, modify and delete them beyond any possible recovery or even functional traceability ... So, not discussing that ... And skipping, as well, the fact that in most use cases not all those permissions need to be granted and some of them will suffice ... That’s for you to decide anyway as you will be the the only one who will suffer if your creation happens to be wanting to bite its creator back ... But, let’s hope this won’t happen as I have nothing that I can offer you in that situation except hope and backups if they existed.

##### Why are permissions not set?

Because your filesystem on that drive is of the [FAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table) family and those folks don't understand or accept Linux type permissions.

##### Why is that filesystem mounted with such limited permissions anyway?

Because, it's mounted with the `fmask=0022` and the `dmask=0022` mount options and those masks translate to `0755` or `rwxr-xr-x` permissions for directories and "actually" `0644` or `rw-r--r--` for regular files.

##### What are the options?

- Change the mount options of `dmask` and `fmask` to the value of `0000` which will translate to the permissions of `0777` and `0666` for directories and files respectively ... Or, probably, alternatively remove those and use `umask=0000` instead which should comparatively affect both directories and files.
- Format that media ( **!!! will erase it !!!** ) to a filesystem of the *nix family e.g. EXT4 as those will allow setting Linux type permissions and even ACLs, see for example [How to grant full access to any new folders/files/subfolders created in a specific folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1494805/968501).
- If using SAMBA for your shares, look into setting specific [`USERSHARES`](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html) options, see for example [How to create a Samba share that is writable from Windows without 777 permissions?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/206309/471459).

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But I did not find yet a few things: I have re-formatted the HDD as ext4 volume, created  a folder in terminal but not in GUI. What should I do next?