# Can't access www-data directory as a root user on my nfs share

Tags: server, permissions, mount, docker, nfs

I have an nfs share mounted on my server, who acts as storage for my Nextcloud instance. As usual the directory is owned by the www-data user. After a restart of my docker containers, there were permitted to write to the corresponding directories. To fix this I tried to change the directory permissions as the root user of the server.
The directories have the following permissions:

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data   49 Jan 25  2020 app
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   19 Jan 25  2021 db
drwxr-xr-x 1 www-data www-data   20 May 18  2020 docker
```

When I run `chown root:root -R app` the server produces the following output:

```
chown: cannot read directory 'app/data': Permission denied
chown: cannot read directory 'app/custom_apps': Permission denied
chown: changing ownership of 'app/themes/example/core/css/server.css': Operation not permitted
```

*(shortened it slighly... the pattern repeats for every sub directory)*

Already tried to run it as the www-data user, which doesn't work and also running the commands inside the docker container aren't working.

My `/etc/fstab`:

`XXXXXXX:/mnt/user/directory    /home/user/cloud/    nfs    defaults,acl    0 0`

Thanks in advance
Regards
Nick

Comment: What is the actual filesystem on the NFS server? Not all filesystems support *nix type permissions … See for example: https://askubuntu.com/a/1495262

Comment: Is the file system exported with `root_squash` from the NFS server? This option can have different names depending on the server.