# How to retain 777 permission on a Subfolder and it's Subfolder and files?

Tags: permissions, 22.04, execute-command

I have created a folder xyz & gave 777 permission on that folder, along with its Subfolder and files with full permission.

I want that if any user creates a Subfolder or files inside xyz folder that files or subfolder should retain 777 permission.

How can I do that on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS?

Comment: Please see ... [How to grant full access to any new folders/files/subfolders created in a specific folder?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1494805)

Comment: @Raffa, Now I understand the question. But still the command is only giving full permission to the subfolders and not the files

Comment: @Ajay Files are never granted the execute permission even with a default `0777` ACL or an `0000` mask ... those translate to `0666` for files ... Please see more discussion here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1495262 ... The execution bit has to be set on a per file basis (or recursively) manually ... That's out of control for the user as the system call that sets it behaves this way ignoring the execution bit on files when reading default ACLs or masks.

Comment: Have you checked [Access Control List (ACLs)](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_22.04&p=acl)?